# Counting Integer Partitions using Type Vectors

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

> Use type vectors to establish the bijection between partitions of n into k parts with the smallest part equal to 1 and partitions of n-1 into k-1 parts.

Okay, I'm going to be honest and say I have no clue how to start. I know all the pre-requisite knowledge but can't seem to put the dots together.

Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what is a "type vector" ? because without using them the bi-jection is quite obvious

Comment: @GCab a type vector is just a representation of how you're partitioning an integer. for example, if you partition 5 into 4 parts, the type vector to demonstrate your partition would be [(1$^3$)*(2$^1$)], which is equivalent to saying 5=1+1+1+2 or 3(1)+1(2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since partitions are lists ( however you want to encode them) of $k$ non-increasing natural
numbers summing to $n$, if the minimum part is fixed to be $1$ it means that the last number of the list is just $1$ and you are left with an initial portion of the string of $k-1$ elements  summing to $n-1$